# How to mock a method with a return value if there is a void method inside this method

Tags: java, android, junit, mockito

I am testing a class that has a testable method (the method itself below) with a return value.
Using Mockito I am having a problem. Problem with void method roomDao.updateData(outData);

```
public IEntity getData(SimBasket<DataEntity, SimRequest> request) {
    Entity outData = converterData.convertNetToDatabase(request);
    roomDao.updateData(outData);
    return outData;
}
```

Here is my test code:

```
@Test
public void getData() {
    simRepo = new SimRepo();
    Mockito.when(simRepo.getData(request)).thenReturn(new Entity());
}
```

Error log:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.CannotStubVoidMethodWithReturnValue:
> 'updateData' is a *void method* and it *cannot* be stubbed with a *return value*!
> Voids are usually stubbed with Throwables:
> doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();

I don't seem to really understand how to fix this, since the void method is inside a method with a return value.

Comment: anywhere you are mocking `roomDao` ?

Comment: If you want to mock `SimRepo`, why do you initialize it with `new SimRepo()` and not `Mockito.mock(SimRepo.class)`?

Comment: @Smutje the issue has been resolved, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `new SimRepo()` try mock it by using Mockito's mock method:

```
@Test
public void getData() {
    SimRepo simRepo =Mockito.mock(SimRepo.class);
    Mockito.when(simRepo.getData(request)).thenReturn(new Entity());
}
```

Update:
If you also want to count the number of times this mock method called use this:

```
// this will check if mock method getData() with parameter `request` called exactly 1 times or not.

Mockito.verify(simRepo, Mockito.times(1)).getData(request);
```

Comment: This works for me, thanks.
But can you tell me one more thing?
How can I check if methods have been called inside the getData () method and how many times?

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help <3.